# Why does this docker-compose command fail while docker run command succeeds?

Tags: perl, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
db:
    image: postgres
search:
    image: elasticsearch
web:
    build: .
    working_dir: /code
    environment:
        CATALYST_CONFIG_LOCAL_SUFFIX: development
    volumes:
        - .:/code
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
    links:
        - db
        - search
    command: carton exec plackup -E development bicycleevents_web.psgi -p 8000
```

Edit: and the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes build-essential curl libssl-dev postgresql-client libpq-dev perl-doc
RUN apt-get clean

RUN curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
RUN cpanm Carton
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN rm -rf /code/local/
RUN carton install
```

If I run `docker-compose up` the `carton exec ...` command fails:

```
$ docker-compose up
...
Starting bicycleeventsweb_web_1
web_1    | Error while loading /code/bicycleevents_web.psgi: Can't locate Moose.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Moose module) (@INC contains: /code/lib /code/local/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /code/lib/BicycleEvents/Web.pm line 2.
web_1    | BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /code/lib/BicycleEvents/Web.pm line 2.
web_1    | Compilation failed in require at /code/bicycleevents_web.psgi line 6.
web_1    | BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /code/bicycleevents_web.psgi line 6.
bicycleeventsweb_web_1 exited with code 2
...
```

However, if I run the same command manually on the container, it succeeds:

```
$ docker run -i -t -e "CATALYST_CONFIG_LOCAL_SUFFIX=development" bicycleeventsweb_web carton exec plackup -E development bicycleevents_web.psgi -p 8000
...
HTTP::Server::PSGI: Accepting connections at http://0:8000/
```

Any thoughts on what is different between the two commands?

For reference [carton](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carton) is like Bundler for Perl. Using `carton exec` should setup the Perl environment so that the appropriate library paths are included that contain all the application specific dependencies - as works with the `docker run` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can we see the Dockerfile that's being built, please? (I lack the reputation to ask in a comment. *Edit: Thanks!* )

**(Edit:)**

One difference I notice is that you're mounting `.` to `/code` in your docker-compose file, but you're not when running the command manually. I'm not familiar with Carton specifically, but if it's creating artifacts inside `/code` when you're executing `carton install` in the Dockerfile, you might be losing them as a result of your docker-compose `volumes` definition.

Comment: Sure, I've added the Dockerfile as well. The web container has already been built by this point.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by the volumes definition? The library artefacts are installed under the code directory so this sounds like the right area..

Comment: Okay, I've commented out the `volumes` definition and it now does start. I think I copied that from a Django or Rails example, I'll need to look up what it does but I'm a step further now! How I actually view my application in a browser will be the next challenge. Thanks.

Comment: Definition, meaning where you had `volumes:` defined in the docker-compose.yml. That has the effect of mounting a location at or below the level of your docker-compose.yml into the container when docker-compose starts it. In this case, mounting `.` to `/code` was replacing the built project with your project root from outside the container, presumably sans build artifacts.